# undefined symbol: libusb_free_config_descriptor

Tags: raspbian, python-3, shared-libraries

I try to use a Chafon UHF RFID reader via USB with Pi Zero.

The manufacturer asked me for installing this:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

and use this Python code:

## UsbDemo.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import ctypes
import time
import platform

import ctypes
from ctypes import *

#Objdll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('E:\\python\\USB\\CFHidApi.dll')
Objdll = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libCFHidApi.so")
print(Objdll)

iUsbNum = int(0)
iUsbNum = Objdll.CFHid_GetUsbCount()
if iUsbNum == 0:
    print("No USB Device")
if Objdll.CFHid_OpenDevice(0) == 1:   # open device
    print("OpenSuccess")
else:
    print("OpenError")

Objdll.CFHid_ClearTagBuf()    # start to get data

from ctypes import *
import time

while True:
    arrBuffer = bytes(9182)
    iTagLength = c_int(0)
    iTagNumber = c_int(0)
    ret = Objdll.CFHid_GetTagBuf(arrBuffer, byref(iTagLength), byref(iTagNumber))
    if iTagNumber.value > 0:
        iIndex = int(0)
        iLength = int(0)
        bPackLength = c_byte(0)
        for iIndex in range(0,  iTagNumber.value):
            bPackLength = arrBuffer[iLength]
            str2 = ""
            str1 = ""
            str1 = hex(arrBuffer[1 + iLength + 0])
            str2 = str2 + "Type:" + str1 + " "  # Tag Type
            str1 = hex(arrBuffer[1 + iLength + 1])
            str2 = str2 + "Ant:" + str1 + " Tag:"  # Ant
            str3 = ""
            i = int(0)
            for i in range(2, bPackLength - 1):
                str1 = hex(arrBuffer[1 + iLength + i])
                str3 = str3 + str1 + " "
            str2 = str2 + str3   # TagID

            str1 = hex(arrBuffer[1 + iLength + i + 1])
            str2 = str2 + "RSSI:" + str1      # RSSI
            iLength = iLength + bPackLength + 1
            print(str2)    # print information
    time.sleep(1)
```

```
-bash-5.0$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:7663 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a86:e010 QinHeng Electronics 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

-bash-5.0$ ls /lib/libCFHidApi.so 
/lib/libCFHidApi.so

-bash-5.0$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/lib/

-bash-5.0$ ls -la
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi   pi    4096 Jan  7 20:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 pi   pi    4096 Jan  7 20:39 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 31924 Jan  7 20:36 libCFHidApi.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi    1711 Jan  7 20:21 UsbDemo.py
```

But if I run, I got the this error:

```
-bash-5.0$ python3 UsbDemo.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UsbDemo.py", line 11, in <module>
    Objdll = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libCFHidApi.so")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./libCFHidApi.so: undefined symbol: libusb_free_config_descriptor
```

Comment: where did you get `libCFHidApi.so` from? you say you did everything from the user guide ... which user guide?

Comment: I've downloaded from the manufacturer page: http://www.chafon.com/DownLoad.aspx?page=3
I use choose ARM&RASPBERRY / 32bit / USBDemo

Comment: You should post [all the commands](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2197/33476) you executed which lead from a reproducible working state to the point you got the error message. There's a chance you made a mistake following the guide, and if you only tell us you did everything the guide says, we will never find it.

Comment: Also, did you try contacting their tech support? They could at least confirm it is compatible with your Pi and OS version, and whether that missing symbol should be there or not.

Comment: Dear Dmitry, you’re right, and thank you for the reply. Sey, it is compatible with pi zero, there is example codes from the manufacturer, but are not working for me. I sent all of the errors to the manufacturer, but he only send me the same again, and again. I will soon semd the details again, but I think, I did send you everything.

Comment: Dear Dmitry, thank you for your patiente, I updated my question.